# Getting a property from parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added a view controller as child like this:

```
UIViewController *sendViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"send"];
[self addChildViewController:sendViewController];
```

In the sendViewController I got this property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet StringInputTableViewCell *nameCell;
```

and in that class I can do something like `self.nameCell.textField.text = @"test";` to set the textField to test

But how can I get this text thats filled in the textField in the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing model and view, thus **breaking the MVC design pattern**.

You should not try to read what is the content of a UI element. Rather you should have all the data (i.e. model) and the view (i.e. the UI, such as text fields) managed by a controller.

There are (easy) ways to get to this information, but I strongly advise you *not* to go down that road!

Comment: Well I guess the controller that manages those is the sendViewController, but I added this controller as a child on another controller and in that controller I need to get the TextField information

Comment: No, you don't. You need a good model structure that tells you what the text in this text field should be.

Answer (score 0):

Basic inheritance between the parent and child class should allow you to pass the property forward.

You'll need to create a child object of the class say **obj**. Then to get the text value of the field you'll use (in the parent class)

```
id obj = [[ChildClassName alloc] init];
NSString *myChildsText = obj.nameCell.textField.text;  // will get the value @"test" as assigned in the childclass.
```

Or of course, you can create a getter and setter in the Child Class for your @property. For example ::

```
- (IBOutlet)nameCell {
 // returns the value
}

- (IBOutlet)setNameCell :(StringInputTableViewCell)newValue {
 //set the value to the @synth value here… 
}
```

then you can call the child objects getters/setters as below ::

NSString *text = [obj nameCell]; //etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4 approaches in here

a) keep reference to you childviewcontroller -> get the value directly
b) use delegate method ( best for observing changes in your textfield )
c) send NSNotification -> this comes with overhead, well at certain points it can help you a lot
d) KVO

Comment: If you send a notification, can you pass a variable with that notification?